# Stop embedded music AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

**N.B.** : I called the sound variables in a different way than the one suggested as duplicate. That's why it's not the same structure to follow as a start of the question, 
 
In my application, i have used the following lines to embed music and run in on actual devices through adobe air :

```
[Embed(source = '/inspiration.mp3')]
        private var MyBack:Class;
        private var back:Sound;
```

Later on, whenever i want to play it, i use the following code :

```
back = (new MyBack()) as Sound;
back.play(0,9999);
```

It works perfectly, the problem is when i want to stop that music! I've used

back.stop();
but it's always telling me

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method stop through a reference with static type flash.media:Sound.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actionscript: Stopping sound in Adobe Flash CS4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980789/actionscript-stopping-sound-in-adobe-flash-cs4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the resultant `SoundChannel` object and then use that one to stop a playing sound.

```
var backPlaying:SoundChannel;
....
backPlaying=back.play(0,9999);
....
backPlaying.stop();
```

Of course, make it so that `backPlaying` is persistent, aka define it in the class aside `back`.